# How to remove the focus border of a field after valid input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms

I have an modal appointment form in my Laravel project. When I am trying to submit the form without feeling any input fields, it gives error with a red border.

[image: error message with focus and red border]

But if I fill-up the `Patient Name` field and click the second field `Phone Number` the error with red border of the first field is still showing.

[image]

So I want to auto remove the red border with error message of every field whenever it have valid input value.

**Here is my form**

```
<form id="appointment-form" action="" method="get" style="margin-top: 3rem;">

<div class="gaps">
    <p>Patient Name</p>
    <input type="text" id="patient_name" name="Patient Name" placeholder="" style="border-left:2px solid #0B6FB2"/>
    <div id="patient_name_error" class="val_error"></div>
</div>  
<div class="gaps">  
    <p>Phone Number</p>
    <input type="text" id="patient_number" name="Number" placeholder="" style="border-left:2px solid #0B6FB2"/>
    <div id="patient_number_error" class="val_error"></div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="add" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Make an appointment" style="padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px; color: #fff; margin-top:20px;">Make an appointment
    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is my script**

```
$('#add').click(function(event)
{               
var patient_name = $('#patient_name').val();
var patient_number = $('#patient_number').val();

if(patient_name.trim() == '' )
{
   $('#patient_name_error').text('Please Provide Your Name');
   $('#patient_name').css({'border' : '1px solid red'});
   $('#patient_name').focus();
   return false;
}
else
{
    $('#patient_name_error').hide();
    $('#patient_name').css({'border' : '0px','border-bottom' : '2px solid #0B6FB2', 'border-left' : '2px solid #0B6FB2'});
}

if(patient_number.trim() == '' )
{
    $('#patient_number_error').text('Please Provide Your Contact Number');
    $('#patient_number').css({'border' : '1px solid red'});
    $('#patient_number').focus();
    return false;
}
else
{
    if(isNaN(patient_number))
    {
        $('#patient_number_error').text('Please Provide Numbers only');
        $('#patient_number').css({'border' : '1px solid red'});
        $('#patient_number').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#patient_number_error').hide();
        $('#patient_number').css({'border' : '0px', 'border-bottom' : '2px solid #0B6FB2', 'border-left' : '2px solid #0B6FB2'});
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please consider using class and CSS to change borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this :

```
$('#appointment-form').click(function () {

var patient_name = $('#patient_name').val();
var patient_number = $('#patient_number').val();


if ($('#patient_name_error').text() && patient_name.trim() != '') {
    $('#patient_name_error').hide();
    $('#patient_name').css({'border' : '0px','border-bottom' : '2px solid #0B6FB2', 'border-left' : '2px solid #0B6FB2'});
   }

if ($('#patient_number_error').text() && patient_number.trim() != '' && !isNaN(patient_number)) {
      $('#patient_number_error').hide();
      $('#patient_number').css({'border' : '0px', 'border-bottom' : '2px solid #0B6FB2', 'border-left' : '2px solid #0B6FB2'});
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto remove the red border with the error message of every field whenever it has valid input value, you should bind the "input" event for every textbox.e.g.-

`$('#patient_name').on('input',function(){
$('#patient_name_error').hide();
$('#patient_name').css({'border' : '0px','border-bottom' : '2px solid #0B6FB2', 'border-left' : '2px solid #0B6FB2'});
});`